# Why these ImageButtons(delete and update) are overlaying

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

this .xml will be the layout of the item in the RecycleView list, but the last two Buttons are overlaying

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#Ffffff"


    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/favorite"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="25dip"
            android:layout_height="25dip"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/nofavorite"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Rihanna Love the way lie"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/artist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Just gona stand there and ..."
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_view" />


    <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/update"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/nofavorite"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/artist" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:src="@drawable/favorite"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/artist"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

they should be in the end of the right, in the end the DELETE button and in the left of this button but in the right end of the screen the UPDATE button, i will bind something to this buttons later

and another question, how can i make a divider btw the items?

thank you =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you use `layout_alignRight="@+id/artist"` on both images which essentially align right edges of the 2 images with the right edge of the View with id artist. To achieve what you want, use `layout_alignParentRight="true"` on the DELETE button and `layout_toLeftOf="@+id/delete"` on the UPDATE button. By the way, why do you need layout_weightSum on the parent. It only works with LinearLayout.

For making divider between items, you can either use a background with the left (right) border on one of the items or put a view between them.

Answer (score 1):

Your buttons need to have attributes setting their position relatively to each other. At the moment, the only indication regarding their position is:

```
 android:layout_alignRight="@+id/artist"
```

That is not enough to place your components since you are using a RelativeLayout (which is good). I suggest you play around with the parameters using the visual editor in you IDE.

One thing to keep in mind is that the component described last in your XML file is the one which should have the position attributes relativ to the other component. So in your case, your DELETE button.